# SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON

Tags: node.js, reactjs

This is a [PERN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solution_stack#Examples) app. I don't remember ever getting this error, and I haven't found any records when doing a Google search.

I don't see anything wrong in the *index.html* file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
      user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <!-- <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" /> -->
    <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Where could it come from? I get it as soon as I start the app.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to parse an HTML document as if it is JSON. That's not going to work, because HTML is not JSON... Without further information about your app, it's impossible to tell why it's trying to do this.

Comment: HTML is indeed invalid JSON. Somewhere you have code that expects JSON and gets HTML back. Check where that is, what the result is which will also probably give you a clue what's wrong. E.g., you might be getting an HTML page with an error.

Comment: Did you figure this out - I'm struggling to solve the same problem

Answer (score 35):

I'm just a beginner, but it happens when you are passing the wrong URL to the fetch function. Suppose that your *db.json* file is running on port 8000 and you are passing port 3000. That's why.

```
useFetch("http://localhost:3000/blogs/" + id);
```

Instead, try the following. It might help. :)

```
useFetch("http://localhost:8000/blogs/" + id);
```

Comment: You're right bro. It's fetch url problem

Comment: How can a JSON file run on a (TCP) port?

Comment: I second this. It happened to me as well when my client and server were running on 2 different ports and the client making the API call at it's own port (instead of server port). Solution was to set up COORS on the server and then add correct port while calling the API from the client (either by specifying the complete URL like in the answer above) or use proxying in client side.

Answer (score 5):

I had this same error when I installed: [`npm gh-pages`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gh-pages).

My solution was to delete the Homepage link in [package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json/) file and it worked.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.

If you are using a Node.js server, install this:

`npm install body-parser`

And add these lines in your server-side code:

`const bodyParser = require("body-parser"); router.use(bodyParser.json());`

Comment: Im sorry for answering on. but ur answer isnt clear because i have installed the `body-parser` package and added the following lines but the router isnt defined

Comment: if you are using app ( `const app = express(); `) then you can simply use `app.use(bodyParser.json()); ` in your code, router is an extra package i have installed for easier routing between urls.

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to fetch data from the backend into my [React](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/React_(JavaScript_library)) application, without mentioning the proper path of the URL in the loader function of the *react-router* library. Hence this issue occurred and once I defined the correct path, it worked just fine.

```
const response = await fetch("http://localhost:8080/events");
```

I forgot to mention "events" in the URL.

Answer (score 2):

Try this header and accept while fetching the URL and the problem should be resolved:

```js
const response = await fetch(url, {
  headers:{
    accept: 'application/json',
    'User-agent': 'learning app',
  }
});
```

Comment: @Aaron Thanks I forgot to add the headers, and solved it!

Answer (score 1):

I'm new at this, but I found if I added a proxy to my [package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json/) file (client side, not server side) it worked!

It looks like this in package.json (placed above my dependencies):

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:3001",
```

I believe it's because the client side can't read it, and the proxy tells it to pass it to the server side which can read it.

Comment: Re *"the proxy tells it to pass it to the server side"*: Is there a source to back that up?

Answer (score 1):

Check if you are calling your API prefixed with the protocol, like 'https://apiurl...', not like 'api.something'.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue and my JSON path was incorrect. Initially, it was `fetch('./movies.json')` which was the incorrect path.

I fixed it, and now it is working fine:

```
  useEffect(() => {
      fetch('../movies.json')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => setMovies(data.posts))

    }, [])
```

Answer (score 1):

I was also faced with the same issue with [React](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/React_(JavaScript_library)).

1. While fetching the JSON, always use a *try*-*catch* block to identity the error
2. Check fetching from locally or server side. If it is a local JSON file, then make sure there is an absolute path and relative path (example: *public/data/mock.json*)
3. Check the JSON file is valid or not (should not have any error)
4. This is the error for me: It's always a good practice to double check the structure of your JSON data and ensure that you are using the correct keys in your code.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar issue with the React application. I was trying to access data from a locally hosted JSON file. After spending almost an hour I figured out that it was just a path issue. I tried using a relative path and it worked for me! I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

From your code snippet, it looks like you're working in a React app.

The `npm run build` command is to create the production build, so it won't give you the level of error detail you want.

Run `npm start` first to run your development server, then you'll see much more detail in your error messages in your browser console, and you can debug from there.

Answer (score -1):

I got the same error while deploying a [React](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/React_(JavaScript_library)) application on [Vercel](https://github.com/vercel/vercel). It turns out I forgot to add environment variables to the project settings in Vercel.

Answer (score -1):

I used GitHub's workspace with two projects and one project called the other project's handle, but I forgot to make the other project's port (3000) public.

Make it public, and it's OK.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

The error message specifically mentions "<!DOCTYPE", which is the start of a document type declaration in HTML. It suggests that you are trying to parse HTML content as JSON, which would cause the error since HTML and JSON have different syntax and structure.

I got the same error for the following code in [React](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/React_(JavaScript_library)):

```
const response = await fetch("https://swapi.dev/api/film/");
```

There was a spelling mistake in the above URL. The correct URL is as follows:

```
const response = await fetch("https://swapi.dev/api/films/");
```

There was a **s** missing in the URL at the last. Please try to check if the URL is providing any data, in the JSON format wherever you trying to fetch it.

A simple solution would be to try and run the URL in the browser and see if it provides JSON data. If it doesn't provide any JSON data then that is not a correct URL for fetching JSON data.

Try some other URL.

Answer (score -1):

When you get this error, make sure your Node.js server is running and fetching data from *http://localhost:8000/dbname*.